# Stop pseudo element scrolling with overflow auto

Tags: html, css

I have a [code block](https://jsfiddle.net/sansSpoon/e8hzqdzu/5/) being generated by Jekyll (Markdown) with PRISM syntax highlighting and want to add a bottom right bevel. I've added a pseudo after element to create the bevel, but when the code block scrolls, the bevel scrolls with it. Is it possible to fix the bevel to the bottom right without having to add a new element?

```
<pre class=" language-bash">
  <code class=" language-bash">$ This is a code block with it's overflow set to auto.
  I'd like to have a bottom right bevel. Unfortunately when it scrolls, the "pseudo bevel" scrolls with the content.
  I'm using Jekyll (Markdown) for the HTML and modifying the CSS from PRISM.
  Is it possible to make the pseudo bevel stay fixed in the bottom right corner?</code>
</pre>

<style type="text/css">
pre[class*="language-"],
:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
    background: #ccc;
}

/* Code blocks */
pre[class*="language-"] {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 .5em .5em -.5em  black inset;
}

pre[class*="language-"]:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-width: 16px 22px 0  0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc rgba(243, 245, 246, 1);
    display: block; width: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: did you try `position:fixed` on your `pre[...]:after`?

Comment: unfortunately `position:fixed` is relative to the browser window, not the containing element.

Comment: wasn't sure after your pre itself is relative. what about putting a :before on the following tag (pre + *) with absolute and z-index?

Comment: I'm using Jekyll (Markdown) to build the html, so unfortunately wrapping the code block in an additional div breaks the formatting. Thanks for details on the root cause though. I'm also running into some issues with the scroll bar in Firefox being positioned below the bevel. I think I'll have to look for a alternative to the pseudo element.